# Use "external"properties in README.adoc in github

Tags: github, asciidoc

I'm using asciidoc to have the readme of my github project. The thing is that I want to create a property,

:latest-version: 0.0.1 that I would like to be updated every time I run gradlew clean build. I was reading that it's possible with preprocessors, but, since I am not "converting" the file, since github is doing it, does it exist any other alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub's Asciidoc renderer does not allow the use of the `include` macro, so you cannot use a separate file to define an attribute, or plain text, to reflect your project version.

Unfortunately, that means that whenever you push a new version of your project, you'll have to also commit an updated `README.adoc` file that includes the updated version string.